# JQuery Slider not working properly with camanJS Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, camanjs

i want to manipulate contrast of an image with jquery slider, but when jquery slider is triggerd the image transforms to a solid black, white, gray, dark gray, light gray and etc, depends on slider range.

[camanJS Plugin](http://camanjs.com/)

```
var $this;
 Caman("#canvas", "/Images/pic.png", function () {
            $this = this;
   });
 $("#slider-range").slider({
       min: -100,
       max: 100,
       value: 0,
       slide: function (event, ui) {
          $this.contrast(ui.value).render();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var caman = Caman("#canvas", "/Images/pic.png");
$("#slider-range").slider({
   min: -100,
   max: 100,
   value: 0,
   slide: function (event, ui) {
        caman.contrast(ui.value).render();
   }
});
```

Comment: i try to do this, http://jsfiddle.net/prince4prodigy/xRDP5/  but image not loaded. i think camanJS resource not attached.